# iphone xml parses text but no images or paragraph spacing

Tags: iphone, xml, image, parsing, blogs

i am trying to parse an xml blog found here: http://www.feed43.com/1515171705611023.xml

it has pictures **within the text**. I am able to parse the headers, the content and the link of the individual posts.

I, however, cannot get it to parse the paragraph spacing links within the text or images. all three of these are EXTREMELY important.

I am using this: http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser  with very few changes. most them having to do with appearances and the actual feed loaded as well as using a scroll view for the detail view instead of the table view shown.

note: it didnt load these things before I made changes either.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an html renderer, not an xml parser.  On iPhone, that is WebKit, which can be used through UIWebView.

Extract the html embedded in the rss formatted xml and place it in a UIWebView using loadHTMLString.  Usually, the baseURL will be the same as the rss source, without the filename.

Comment: ok so render the html in a webView. if I have the contents of one of the rss entries inside a string already is there a way to just load the webView with the contents of that string?

Comment: OMG I FIGURED I OUT 

thank you soooooo much. turns out it was a problem in my xml parser removing all the tags wow i feel stupid now.